Unable to create virtualenv env in flask
I am not able to create virtualenv env in my VS code, i have tried multile times, have checked multiple youtube videos howeer its still not running, could anybody please assist, screenshot also attached
multiple Youtube videos and artiles i have read but its still not working

PS C:\New folder\Python> pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\91701\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (20.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.7 in c:\users\91701\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.12.2 in c:\users\91701\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<5,>=3.9.1 in c:\users\91701\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (4.2.0)
PS C:\New folder\Python> virtualenv env
virtualenv : The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ virtualenv env
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Unless there's a specific reason you want to use virtualenv, try using venv from stdlib instead via python -m venv venv.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22The+term+virtualenv+is+not+recognized+as+the+name+of+a+cmdlet%2C+function%2C+script+file%2C+or+operable+program%22

Try using python -m virtualenv venv to create it.
Also, check if virtualenv is in PATH.
